# Application to download default page from website?

Tags: windows, web-apps

I have list of URLs and I want to download only the default or index pages from these URLs.
I have used WinHTTrack Website Copier but it is not efficient, because it does not download all URL list as well as it downloads many folders for one URL.

If there are any applications better than WinHTTrack it will be great .

Comment: Why is WinHTTrack not efficient?

Comment: because it does not download all url list as well as it downloads many folders for one url

Comment: Isn't that a question of configuration? See: [mirror single page with httrack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968470/mirror-single-page-with-httrack). For a more details "tutorial", also see [Configuring WinHTTrack to Back Up a Blog](https://raywoodcockslatest.wordpress.com/2014/02/11/configuring-winhttrack/): *a Maximum mirroring depth of 1 would capture only the single page found at the designated URL*

Comment: One more thing is we will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. "Better than" is mostly a subjective term, we need facts :)

Answer (score 1):

WinHTTrack is a very good tool, but it requires some extra work to properly retrieve the correct pages and files that fits exactly what we need.

A simple approach may be:

- Use firefox browser
- Install [Scrapbook](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/scrapbook/) addon and make the scrapbook sidebar visible
- If your url list is an html file then:
  1 open it in firefox.
  2 in the scrapbook sidebar go to tools->save multiple urls.
  3 in the URL-detector pull-down menu select 'All links in the page'.
  4 click 'save all tabs'
- If your url list is a plain txt file then:
  1 install the [linky](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/linky/) addon in firefox.
  2 open the url list file in firefox.
  3 right button in the url list file page, and select 'open all selected TEXT links in tabs'.
  4 in the scrapbook sidebar, tools->save multiple urls.
  5 in the URL-detector pull down menu select 'All open tabs in the window'
  6 click 'save all tabs'

You can see the downloaded folders (one folder per url) in the scrapbook sidebar, tools->open data folder.

Cheers